# from . import stuff in python

Tags: python

I am trying to understand this piece of code written in python in a Django App

```
from . import views
```

I haven't come across anything like this in the python documentation. Can somebody explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a relative import.  It lets you import modules from the same package without specifying the package name. So, if you're in the foo.views module, instead of:

```
from foo.models import Model
```

you can do:

```
from .models import Model
```

This lets you change the package name without refactoring all the imports in that package.

Answer (score 0):

This was introduced with [PEP-328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), and describes a relative import.

Essentially, it means: `from the current package/directory import views`.